# Job service is not called

Tags: android, service, android-service, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

Hi I referred Job scheduler from this [link](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/jobscheduler). When I want to start a service  from the activity button click  the service is not started. I had listed the code. Can any one help where I went wrong?

**MainActivity**

```
  package com.example.samplejobscheduler;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
    public void scheduleJob(View v) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MySchedulerService.class);
    JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setPeriodic(2 * 60 * 1000)
            .build();
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
    if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
    }
}
public void cancelJob(View v) {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    scheduler.cancel(123);
    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled");
}}
```

**MySchedulerService**

```
public class MySchedulerService extends JobService {
private static final String TAG = "MySchedulerService";
private boolean jobCancelled = false;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job started");
    doBackgroundWork(params);

    return true;
}

private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "run: " + i);
                if (jobCancelled) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Job finished");
            jobFinished(params, false);
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before completion");
    jobCancelled = true;
    return true;
}}
```

**activity_main**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.samplejobscheduler.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="scheduleJob"
        android:text="Schedule Job" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="cancelJob"
        android:text="Cancel Job" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.samplejobscheduler">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MySchedulerService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.samplejobscheduler"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the min SDK is 21 or higher.

And in manifest I don't think you need this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Yes bro .. SDK is 21 only and I removed  the permission  from the manifest file still service is not called.

Answer (score 0):

After Analysing your code, I will suggest..

```
.setRequiresCharging(true)
```

As you have set required charging true, so Service will only run, If your device is in charging, If it not charging, It will not run.

```
.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
```

As you have set the above condition, then Your service will run only if your device is connected with wifi, If your device is connected with a mobile data connection, service will not run. If you just want service should run only when the internet is available whether be it mobile data or wifi, then set below condition

```
 .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
```

Another thing, you have not added exported flag value to true for the job in the manifest, make it like this below

```
    <service
        android:name=".MySchedulerService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```